# Job for create/import data from csv

Tags: 7, nodes, cron, importing-exporting

I need to import a large amount of contents of a CSV file.
The file is a bit complex and still have a folder with a lot of images that are associated with each line of the csv.

As the file is complex and there are images to the mix, the existing import modules do not serve me. I'll have to create a script to perform the task.
My problem is that I am amateur in drupal (but experienced in php programming).

- Do I create and run a cron in Drupal?
- How do I programmatically create content?
- How do I programmatically associate images to the content?

Comment: To answer your questions, I have attached references where you will be able to find answers. 1. To Create and Run Cron in Drupal: [function hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7), [Scheduling hook_cron](https://www.drupal.org/node/827118) 2. To Create a content Programmatically: [Drupal 7 - Create a Node in Code](https://www.drupal.org/node/1388922) 3. Associate Images to Node: [Attaching image files to nodes programmatically in Drupal 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129559/attaching-image-files-to-nodes-programmatically-in-d

Comment: Feeds is quite slow for large csv imports, and in most cases it will not complete, I am having the same issue with feeds, I think the solution is to import the data into mysql and map into the desired content type